# Autloading Phalcon Incubator - MongoDB

Tags: phalcon

I have a question about autoloading. I need to use the MongoDB adapter that comes inside the Incubator and I am seeing that in the documentation it says register the namespace Phalcon

```php
<?php
$loader->registerNamespaces([
        'Phalcon' => '/path/to/incubator/Library/Phalcon/',
]);
```

The question I have is:
If I register this namespace, which is the default in the framework, when I ask for Phalcon\Http\Request, what instance I get? The request instance from the incubator or instance that comes with the Framework.

I ask because I have seen in git incubator there are folders for almost all the components that Phalcon already has integrated, such as: Request, Response, Mvc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will find the **namespaces** (folders) `Phalcon\Http\Request`, `Phalcon\Http\Response`, etc. in both the initial framework (extension) and the incubator. There is nothing wrong here.

On the other and, the **classes** (files) `Phalcon\Http\Request` and `Phalcon\Http\Response` only exist in the initial framework. There is no duplicate in the incubator, for reference :

- https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/tree/3.4.x/phalcon/http
- https://github.com/phalcon/incubator/tree/3.4.x/Library/Phalcon/Http

In the same way, the class `Phalcon\Http\Uri` only exists in the incubator.

There is usually no class conflict between both the extension and the incubator. If it would happen, my guess is that the class in the extension would be used.